# Get JPG Meta (People and Location) Attributes in C#

Tags: c#, metadata, jpeg

I have a large image collection, curated with Windows Photo Gallery.  I have made extensive use of the Date Taken, Tags, People and Location Attributes.

Using C# I can get Date Taken and Tags, but I am yet to find a way to get People and Location.

Is there a way?

[image: View from Within Photo Gallery. From right click file properties, you can see People, but not location.]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983766/getting-gps-data-from-an-images-exif-in-c-sharp for geotag data

Comment: Also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129/is-there-an-exif-standard-for-tagging-people-in-photographs

Comment: Thanks for both of those @tofutim however I am pretty sure I have read in the past that MS did not support the standard both for people and location for Photo Gallery Live.  Which I sort of see in other apps, where they get the Tags I have set, but never the people and location. - And I just tried the location example linked to and it returned nothing. Will keep digging just to be sure.

Comment: confirmed, even MetaDataExtractor does not get People and Location

Comment: Do you know what file format the JPEG streams are in?

Comment: What do you mean by JPEG Stream?  I can check.  90% of the photos are from Canon DSLRs, I can get that part of the Metadata ok.  Its only the Photo Gallery meta data I am struggling with.