# Get exif data from a picture in Visual Studio and store it in an access database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exif

I have to make a Visual Studio program that can select a folder where pictures are. Then it has to get them the name 18 (year 2018) A,bc, ... (you just count which letter it is and that the month so: A is January, B is February and so on...) then XX ( 2 numbers that indicate the datum so 04 or 28) and then just 3 numbers that indicate which picture of the day it is (001 first, 002 second, etc.)

I also have to get the place (nearest city from the picture) and the country.

Then I have to place all that information in an access database. (link example in the link (number 6))

If you guys think it's best to get all this info from the exif directly it's ok for me. I'm not a professional so I'm really open for changes or help.

I found some things on internet but I'll link you everything I got now:

1. My thesis (not done yet and it's in Dutch): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h9kdPtZVqBPAOrpHwJkP37LHwsWIPYOn/view?usp=sharing
2. moqup (still working on it): https://app.moqups.com/zarki50@gmail.com/siKbbU1mwA/view
3. https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp
4. [Getting GPS data from an image's EXIF in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983766/getting-gps-data-from-an-images-exif-in-c-sharp)
5. [How to get the EXIF data from a file using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp)
6. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yQp7Rga7FTC_s09TP-pGkwE0USpNqrYj/view?usp=sharing

PS: sorry if my question is not well posed but it's the first time I sent a question and I am not familiar with Stack Overflow.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, i'm still working on Functional analysis for my "client"