# C#: convert GPS data from string to double

Tags: c#, string, converters, degrees

I'm doing project for reading metadata of images. How can I convert GPS data in string like Latitude: 34 deg 30' 28.71" N to decimal degrees in float or double in C#? to running process

Comment: Can you show us what exactly is the string you receive? Maybe you will have to do a converter which suits you. Cheers

Comment: Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983766/getting-gps-data-from-an-images-exif-in-c-sharp) to see if it is really this you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking how you can parse and tokenize a string?

Comment: for example a have the string =(" 34 deg 30'40" ") how can i use any function to convert to value like lat= 34,56

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this simple formula, after extracting values from string.

```
Dim strGPS As String = "Latitude: 34 deg 30' 28.71"" N"

Dim degrees As Double = CDbl(strGPS.Split(Space(1))(1)) '34
Dim minutes As Double = CDbl(strGPS.Split(Space(1))(3).Replace("'", "")) '30
Dim seconds As Double = CDbl(strGPS.Split(Space(1))(4).Replace("""", "")) '28.71

MsgBox(degrees + (minutes / 60) + (seconds / 3600))
```

Comment: how can i extracting this value from string?

Comment: added simple code in VB.NET to extract values from string; you can find better method if you need/want.